# Une minuscule après un point d'exclamation

Tags: orthographe, ponctuation, majuscules

J'ai vu écris cette phrase récemment dans le journal ou un livre :

> Eh bien ! tu assures.

Pourriez-vous me dire pourquoi « tu » ne prend pas un « T » majuscule dans ce cas-là ? Si c'est bien le cas, pourquoi une telle règle a été créée ?

Comment: @Romain VALERI : je ne sais plus si c'était dans un journal ou dans un livre mais le texte était écrit par une personne connaissant l'orthographe. C'est pourquoi cela m'a étonné.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La première lettre d’une phrase prend une majuscule. Effectivement, à part en début de paragraphe, la première lettre d’une phrase est derrière un point, un point d’interrogation, un point d’exclamation ou des points de suspension.

Mais cela ne signifie pas que, derrière chaque point, point d’interrogation, … il faille mettre une majuscule.

Et j’aurais pu écrire « Mais cela ne signifie pas que, derrière chaque point, point d’interrogation, etc., il faille mettre une majuscule. »

En l’occurrence, le point d’exclamation derrière « Eh bien ! » ne marque pas la fin d’une phrase ; il sert juste à souligner le « Eh bien ».  On aurait pu écrire « Eh bien, tu assures. », mais pas « Eh bien. Tu assures. ». Le « tu assures » n’est pas au début de ta phrase ; il ne prend donc pas de majuscule.

Je ne connais pas l’origine de cette pratique. Ceci dit, je doute que l’utilisation systématique d’une majuscule derrière un point d’exclamation ait jamais été la règle.

Ma référence (hors ligne) : M. Grevisse, A. Goosse, *Le Bon Usage* 14<sup>e</sup> édition, De Boeck/Duculot, §98 c) et §123 b) 2<sup>o</sup>.

Comment: Vraiment? Tu aurais un référence en ligne? J'avais jamais vu ça avant...

Comment: @Édouard : ok mais comment savoir quand on doit appliquer cette règle ? Pourquoi une telle règle a été créée ?

Answer (score 3):

Wikipédia utilise pour source le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale* et [note](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_d%27exclamation#Typographie) :

> Le point d'exclamation, tout comme les points d'interrogation ou de suspension, est suivi par une majuscule lorsqu'il est placé en fin de phrase, et non lorsqu'il ne sert qu'à en détacher les éléments successifs.
>
> « Ah ! non ! c'est un peu court, jeune homme !
>       On pouvait dire… Oh ! Dieu !… bien des choses en somme… »
>
> — Edmond Rostand, *Cyrano de Bergerac* (I, 4)
>
> « C'est la femme d'un autre ! ô jalousie affreuse ! »
>
> — Victor Hugo, *Ruy Blas* (II, 3)

Rien du coté d'Orthotypographie sur [ce point](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/point_cardinal-proverbe.html) (seulement sur le point d'interrogation et la conclusion n'est d'ailleurs pas très claire).

Answer (score 2):

Les minuscules après un point d'exclamation ou d'interrogation sont de rigueur dans le cas d'incises :

> — Stop ! cria-t-il.
>   — Il n'en est pas question ! protesta-t-elle.

L'exclamation exige... un point d'exclamation derrière lequel, en l'occurrence, il serait difficile de mettre une majuscule ! « Stop! Cria-t-il. »... serait curieux. Non?

Comment: Sauf que l'exemple cité dans la question n'est pas une incise. Et il demande **pourquoi** cette ponctuation est correcte, cela ne répond pas vraiment à sa question.